# Handsontable fixed header with scrollbar rendering issue on IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, handsontable

I'm using IE9 and IE11, jquery 1.11.1, handsontable 0.12.0

when **scroll down the scroll bar, the "fixed" header seems not being "fixed" with a little shaking in IE**,

but it is normal in Chrome,

do I have to add some config to avoid this?

Thanks!

[here is demo from the official site](http://handsontable.com/demo/fixed.html)

```
 var hot = new Handsontable(container,
  {
    data: data,
    minSpareRows: 1,
    fixedRowsTop: 0,
    colHeaders: true,
    contextMenu: true
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, this seems to be a long-running bug. I'm having this issue too, and while looking for solution, found this link:
https://github.com/handsontable/handsontable/issues/1761.

There is even a gif which shows how this problem looks like, and unfortunately this bug is still not closed.
Authors say that "When there will be any solution provided #1761 gets updated."
So it seems nothing we can do for now, just wait and hope it will be fixed soon.

P.S. Meantime, I have this bug when using the most recent version (currently) - 0.20.3, so it exists for a really long time already.